# How to force Doctrine DateTime to use always UTC?

Tags: datetime, doctrine, timezone, utc

Because the timezone can't be saved in mysql database, I would like to save only UTC time. My scripts are already set to use UTC, but I get times from many external sources. Currently I have to set every dateTime objects timezone to UTC before I save it in the Doctrine Entity and flush it to the DB.

Is there a possibility to tell my doctrine installation, that it always has to do `setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))` before flushing it to database? Currently I do this manually, shouldn't be neccessary

Answer (score 4):

Create a UTCDateTimeType that handles the setTimezone for you.

It is an example in the Doctrine documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html